# creating a function in python and applying it to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Need some help creating and calling a function..

Current code:

```
Table1 = Table1.assign(Field3 = np.where(Table1.Field1.astype(str).str[0:5].isin(['CEQTY','LPCEQ']),
                                         Table1.Field2, 0))
```

Potential function?

```
def func(a,b):
   Table1 = Table1.assign(a = np.where(Table1.Field1.astype(str).str[0:5].isin([b]),
                                       Table1.Field2, 0))
```

Calling the function?

```
Table1.apply(func,a,b)?
```

I am repeating this procedure 100 times and the only thing that changes is `'Field3'` and the arguments in `isin.` 
Keep getting an error when creating the function likely due to syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider replacing [`DataFrame.Apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) since you are not running an exclusive operation on each column or row but conditional logic based on other columns, *Field1* and *Field2*, for *new* columns. Also, [`Dataframe.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) takes an unquoted name which will not work with passed in string.

Instead, run a simple Python function call that assigns column by string then returns a new df. Below demonstrates with random data, seeded for reproducibility, conditionally producing *Fields3-5*:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(55)    
Table1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [np.random.randint(15) for _ in range(50)],
                       'Field1': [np.random.choice(['CEQTY','LPCEQ','ABCDE','WVXYZ','12345'],1).item(0) 
                                  for _ in range(50)],
                       'Field2':  np.random.randn(50)*100
                       }, columns=['ID', 'Field1', 'Field2'])

def func(df):
    # ITERATE THROUGH LIST OF TUPLES (NEW COL AND LIST OF SEARCH ITEMS)
    for i in [('Field3',['CEQTY','LPCEQ']),
              ('Field4',['ABCDE','WVXYZ']),
              ('Field5',['12345'])]:

        # ASSIGN NEW COL, i[0], BY STRING BASED ON SEARCH LIST, i[1]
        df[i[0]] = np.where(df.Field1.astype(str).str[0:5].isin(i[1]), df.Field2, 0) 

    return df

output = func(Table1)    
print(output.head(10))
#    ID Field1      Field2      Field3      Field4     Field5
# 0  13  LPCEQ  105.640854  105.640854    0.000000   0.000000
# 1  10  12345  -13.049038    0.000000    0.000000 -13.049038
# 2   7  CEQTY  -85.079280  -85.079280    0.000000   0.000000
# 3   8  12345   12.047304    0.000000    0.000000  12.047304
# 4  13  12345  -29.095108    0.000000    0.000000 -29.095108
# 5  13  12345  -24.229704    0.000000    0.000000 -24.229704
# 6  13  LPCEQ  -97.472869  -97.472869    0.000000   0.000000
# 7   5  ABCDE -221.743951    0.000000 -221.743951   0.000000
# 8   7  LPCEQ   -0.155842   -0.155842    0.000000   0.000000
# 9   5  CEQTY    2.297829    2.297829    0.000000   0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely receiving a syntax error as you're not calling `func` with the correct syntax.

Use this:

```
Table1.apply(func(a, b))
```

When calling a function, you need to use brackets around the arguments being supplied.

Comment: thanks but the function itself is not running. can you tell the issue in defining the function?